# onPreExecute method in volley

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, android-volley

Is there any method in volley as like `AsyncTask` ?

I am used volley lib in my app and I want do some pre execution in volley. So is there any method in volley lib ad like below methods in `AsyncTask` because I want to create json with Base64 image string and when I going to create json with image my app is stop responding.

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this,"Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        items = parser.getItems();

        for (Item it : items) {
            publishProgress(it);
        }
        return(null);
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Item... item) {
        adapter.add(item[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add a ProgressDialog to your layout, then change its visibility to `View.GONE` on response.

An example of layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ...

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

An example of `volley` library use:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // add your logic here
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        // set you progressBar variable using findViewById method
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

        // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Volley Library has no such method like onPreExecute.

You can initialize variables before invoking querying the request in Volley.

**Here is an Simple example, the piece of code has been taken from the example included with the Volley lib :**

```
     //Here you'll initialize variables like showing dialog etc.


    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            String url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?" +
                        "v=1.0&q=dog&rsz=8";

            JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("Response", response.toString());
                    //Here you'll dismiss dialog :)
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

            queue.add(jsObjRequest);

        }
```

Comment: Yes, but I am adding image in Base64 string in Json so app is stop responding when I am create json in UI thread.

Comment: Can you share log cat ?

Comment: No it's not the log I am looking for. I want the log where your app stops responding.

Comment: My app is not force close but stop responding.

Comment: how to dismiss it?

Comment: do I need to call a `runOnUIthread` ? I'm having skipped frames :(

Comment: No you dont have to. @mori